# How to do this SQL in LINQ

Tags: sql-server, linq

Morning i would like to know how to do this bit of (MS) SQL in LINQ...

```
 SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10),orderDate,110)  AS OrderDate, 
 SUM(1) AS TotalOrders 
 FROM Orders
 WHERE OrderDate>getdate()-30
 GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(10),orderDate,110)
 ORDER BY OrderDate DESC
```

Many thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
I ended using and edited version of the solutions provided below, thought i would share it...

```
 using (DataDataContext dc = new DataDataContext())
        {
            var query = from o in dc.Orders
                        where o.orderDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)
                        let dt = o.orderDate
                        group o by new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day) into g
                        select new OrderCounts
                        {
                            OrderDate = String.Format("{0:d}", g.Key.Date),
                            TotalOrders = g.Count()
                        };

            query.GroupBy(o => o.OrderDate);
            query.OrderBy(o => o.OrderDate);

            return query.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: isn't sum(1) just doing a count? Why use sum(1) when there is a prefectly good (and probably better suited) option available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result =(from s in Orders
             where s.OrderDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)
             group s by new { date = s.OrderDate.ToString() } into g
             // or use ((DateTime)s.OrderDate).ToShortDateString() instead of s.OrderDate.ToString()
             select new
             {
                  OrderDate = g.Key.date,
                  TotalOrders = g.Count()
             }).OrderByDescending(x=>x.OrderDate);;
```

Comment: g.Sum(1) does not seem to want to work? **Error 45 'System.Linq.IGrouping<AnonymousType#1,ABO.amzOrder>' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int>)' has some invalid arguments**

Comment: Just noticed that all the dates are being put into per order, not grouping them, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The query will be

```
var query = from o in res
                        where o.OrderDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)
                        orderby o.OrderDate descending
                        group o by o.OrderDate into g                       
                        select new
                        {
                            OrderDate = g.Key.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
                            ,
                            TotalOrders = g.Sum(i=> 1)
                        };
```

OR by Lambda expression

```
var query= res
                        .Where(i => i.OrderDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30))
                        .OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderDate)
                        .GroupBy(g => g.OrderDate)
                        .Select(s => new { OrderDate = s.Key.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), TotalOrders = s.Sum(i => 1) });
```

Comment: I tried your code, and it too brings back all orders from last 30 days, and is not grouping them by date - i have a datetime field btw.